# Help with identifying weird tree

Tags: identification

We’ve had 3 or 4 arborists over to the house for tree work over the years and we always make sure to ask if they know what one type of tree is. Each arborist has given us different but wrong answers.

I just tried a google image search us My a leaf and that was unsuccessful too.

Can anyone help? We live in Northern California but I’m not sure if the tree is native or not.

The tree is not flowering now, but when it does, it’s yellow and red, and when it drops it looks like yellow hairs scattered about the yard. When the leaves dry up they turn rather sharp and very unpleasant to walk on.

Any guesses?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the interesting leaf-shape, my guess is Silk Oak or "Grevillea robusta". Does it put out large fluffy/feathery yellow-orange clumps of flowers in the....(not sure what time of year)? Looks (from Wikipedia, which calls it "silky oak") like they are in the Protea family and native to Australia, although I have seen plenty of them growing big and tall in Northern California.

Comment: Wow! Mystery solved! That’s exactly what it is! And we’ll described with “fluffy feathery yellow orange clumps”.  Thank you!